# WKWebView show a blank page when loadRequest?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

Thanks for watching!
There's a problem that when i use `WKWebView` and just load a URL, but it will show blank page for seconds although it is loading, then it show whole page.
I add a `UIActivityIndicatorView` in `webView` and remove it when `webView` finish load, but how can i save those seconds? I think those seconds is waste time and give users bad feeling.

Comment: @Kirit Modi sir, i have been correctly show result page, but it won't show immediately, how can i make it show immediately or more quickly?

Comment: have you find some solution to solve this?

Comment: @spartawhy117 Haven't yet, It seems no solution.

Comment: @好多余先生丶some local preloading work such as js css file doesn't help accelerate loading speed?

Comment: @spartawhy117 but it's not our own page

Answer (score 0):

These seconds could be the response time, when webview start loading and expecting some response from server, as soon as it receive response data,  responsible webEngine in OS(iOS or OSX) start loading of task in incremental fashion.

Comment: Yes, it must be. It's so bad to wait response.